# Encryption for storing user credentials

Tags: java, security, firebase-realtime-database, hash

I want to store the user credentials on the realtime cloud database. The basic idea of mine was to use the hashing with double salt and master password to hash it and store hashed credential and used salt.

When I decrypt it I take the master password from user and decrypt the credentials using that with salt stored. But the problem is when user forgets the master password then all the credential data will be scrap since it cannot be decrypted without the combination of salt and master. And I cannot store the master password then it will become vulnerable.

What should I do here to achieve my task?
If anyone has completely different approach then also it would be fine.

Comment: If it comes to security I recommend at least to take a look at widely used libraries (eg. [jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/)) before doing encryption in my own. By the way, you should not be able to decrypt hashes. You maybe want to compare the hashes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it twice. One with the password of the user and a second with a password of your own. With this you will able to create a new one decrypting your copy and creating a new one with the new password of the user.The problem with this is that if you both forget the password then you are doomed.